# finding overlap between two large lists

Tags: python, list

I have two very large lists P and Q and would like to find items in P that are also in Q. I read other threads that suggest using sets, but I'm not sure if that's necessary. I think the following line satisfies the need:

```
overlap = [l for l in P if l in Q]
```

However, I'm wondering if this is a reasonable and fastest way to find the overlap or you would suggest using sets?

Thanks.

Comment: For a large `N` turning `Q` into a `set` will have noticeable performance impact. Currently this is `O(N^2)`, i.e. each item in `P` requires an `O(N)` look up in `Q`. With a set you are talking `O(N)`, each item in `P` requires an O(1) look up in `set(Q)`. There's a `O(N)` construction time for `set(Q)` that vanishes in impact the larger the `N` - so is still described as `O(N)`

Comment: @AChampion: I assume you mean that the OP's algorithm is `O(N^2)`, not that turning `Q` into a set will have that order.

Comment: Yes indeed, apologies if that isn't clear. With more information it might be possible to identify optimal/simple solutions e.g. multisets with `collections.Counter()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @AChampion sets are more efficient for this purpose. Here is the code for those who are interested. You just need to convert the larger list, say Q, to a list, then

```
 larger_list_set = set(Q)
 overlap = [l for l in P if l in larger_list_set]
```

is more efficient.

Comment: If you resort to using sets you might as well use `overlap = set1.intersection(set2)` method.